# Can a Mersenne number be a power (with exponent > 1) of a prime?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $n \geq 1$ and consider the (Mersenne) number $M_n = 2^n-1$. Is it possible that $M_n = p^k$ for some prime $p$ and some (necessarily odd) $k > 1$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why $k$ must be odd?

Comment: Because for even $2^{2n}-1=(2^n-1)(2^n+1)$ and $2^n-1$ and $2^n+1$ are coprime.

Comment: Yes but also because, if $k$ was even, then $p^k \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$ contrary to $2^n-1 \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$ for $n \geq 2$.

Comment: Similar to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2352131/83175.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible. [Catalan's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture) (proved in 2002) states that the only solution of $x^a-y^b=1$ ($x$ and $y$ are positive integers and $a$ and $b$ are integers greater than $1$) is $3^2-2^3=1$.

If a Mersenne's number were the power of a prime, we'd have
$$2^n-1=p^k$$
or
$$2^n-p^k=1$$
contradicting Catalan's conjecture.

Comment: This is very nice: to the point it sounds a bit over the top :). Thanks a lot; I was not even aware of such a nice fact.

Comment: But perhaps there is a more elementary proof?