# What is the longest run of consecutive natural numbers that are prime powers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

So, suppose that we have a natural number,n, that is a prime power. Is there a largest k such that run like this: $n=p^{a_i}_i$,$n+1=p^{a_i}_i$,$n+2=p^{a_i}_i$...$n+k=p^{a_i}_i$,
only goes so far? I was playing around with Mathematica and it seems that for any distance there might be infinitely many prime powers that are within that distance close to each other. I think that my specified distance of 1 can't have a run of length more than two, but am not sure how to prove this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If $n$ is even, then $n+2$ is also even.  It is very rare for both $n$ and $n+2$ to be powers of $2$.  The answer is $4$ from the run: $2$, $3$, $4$,  $5$.

Comment: I think the question might be more interesting if you look at "consecutive odd numbers"

Comment: @lulu You would just apply the same logic with 3 to put an upper bound on it.  And the answer is 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13.

Comment: @btilly  Ah, quite right.

Comment: I think the term "prime power" usually means the exponent is greater than 1.   So I think the only answer here is $k=2$ for $8, 9.$

Comment: @Goddard You are right. It follows from Catalan's conjecture. There is a related post apparently on Stack. [Prime Power Mersenne](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/850694/can-a-mersenne-number-be-a-power-with-exponent-1-of-a-prime).