# Can a Mersenne Number $> 1$ ever be a perfect power?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, exponential-function

Can anyone prove the possibility of a Mersenne Number $2^p-1$ that is a perfect power (i.e. $2^p-1 = a^k$ for integers $(p, a, k) > 1$? There are none known with the conditions mentioned. Thanks for help!

Comment: Similar to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/850694/83175.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that $2^p - a^k = 1$ implies that $2^p$ and $a^k$ are consecutive powers. By [Mihailescu's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture), the only two consecutive powers of natural numbers are

$$3^2 - 2^3 = 1$$

so such $(p, a, k) > 1$ would not exist.